computing the average waiting time for HTT in a infinite coin toss
Let $(X_i)_{i\geq1}$ be a iid sequence of Bernoulli variables with parameter $p$. Let $H_i:=\{X_i=H\}$ and $T_i:=\{X_i=T\}$. Let further $\tau$ be the number of tosses until the pattern HTT appears for the first time in the sequence. I want to use the law of total expectation to compute this. In many books and online resources I find the following argumentation:
$$\mathbb E(\tau)=p\,\mathbb E(\tau|H_1)+(1-p)\,\mathbb E(\tau|T_1)+1.$$
But according to the law of total probability i think it should only be $$\mathbb E(\tau)=p\,\mathbb E(\tau|H_1)+(1-p)\,\mathbb E(\tau|T_1).$$
Curiously enough, both methods deliver the same result when applied consistently. Bote methods deliver the (correct) expression
$$\mathbb E(\tau)=\frac{1}{pq^2}.$$
This implies $\mathbb E(\tau)=8$ for $p=q=1/2$, which is the correct expression, as i computed with other methods.
Is this just a spiel on the interpretation? In the sense that one says the conditional expectation given information of the result of the first coin toss is the remaining time and the other (mine) is the total time given some information on the first coin toss.
Furthermore, intuitively (using the second interpretation) $\mathbb E(\tau| T_1)=1+\mathbb E(\tau)$, since the pattern does not start with tails.
What is the exact way to show that without handwaving arguments?
My computations so far: We know that $\tau\geq 3$ a.s. If we know that the first toss resulted in a tails, $\mathbb P(\{\tau=3\}\cap T_1)=0$. Furthermore $T_1$ and $\{\tau=k\}$ are independent for any $k\geq 4$
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb E(\tau|T_1)
&=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(T_1)}\sum_{k=4}^\infty k\, \mathbb P(\{\tau=k\}\cap T_1)
=\sum_{k=4}^\infty k\,\mathbb P(\tau=k)\\
&=\mathbb E(\tau)-3\,\mathbb P(\tau=3)
=\mathbb E(\tau)-3pq^2.
\end{align*}$$
This means, the independence assumption is wrong.

I don't understand the second equation, the first one seems clearly correct.  In general, I would do it by states, defining states according to how much of the desired sequence you have going.  Thus we have states $\emptyset, H, HT$.  If $S$ is a state then, letting $E_S$ denote the expected number of trials till completetion given that you are starting in state $S$, it is easy to get a system of linear equations connecting the various $E_S$.

For instance:  considering the possible outcomes of the first trial, we get $E_{\emptyset}=1+pE_H+qE_{\emptyset}$.

You might want to compare the expected time for $HTT$ which is indeed $\frac{1}{pq^2}$ with the expected time for $THT$ which is greater, I think  $\frac1q+\frac{1}{pq^2}$

Another thing to think about is that if $p=q=\frac12$then the expected times for $HTT$ and $HHT$ are both $8$, but in a race between them $HHT$ will appear first twice as often as $HTT$.

The method and equations for the second equation are from the paper "Waiting times and expected waiting times - paradoxical situations" by V.C. Hombas. I do not see, how one gets the "+1" using the law of total expectation for the decomposition regarding the outcome of the first coin toss. It simply makes no sense, unless $\tau$ encodes the remaining number of tosses until the pattern HTT appears first. However, this is not how I defined $\tau$.

There is a general way to solve these kinds of problems. See Levin and Peres' Markov Chains and Mixing Times section 17.3.2. Although there is a conventional mistake in that section which I had written to Peres about and he said that he'll add it to the errata but I am unsure if he had done so or not. I had written a small expository note on this using a simple gambling system analogy (which does not require Martingale Theory). If you want I can share it with you or post that as an answer.

I am not interested in alternative computations, but only in the concrete question i asked. There must be a computation that justifies the "+1". It's intuitive but not mathematically sound. Sorry for everyone who put effort in pointing to alternatives.

The +1 just comes because the first toss has already happended. Both methods cannot possibly give the same result as one expression is strictly greater than the other. So there must be some hidden error in what you have done. Applying law of total probability will lead you to the expression $E(\tau)=p(1+E(\tau|H_{1}))+q(1+E(\tau|T_{1}))=pE(\tau|H_{1})+qE(\tau|T_{1})+1$. Most probably, you and the book have a conventional difference in adding $+1$ signifying the restart the process after the first toss. @PeterStrouvelle

@PeterStrouvelle I have updated my answer to clear you doubt.

@Mr.GandalfSauron: Thank you. I understand that the "+1" approach is heavily leaning on the Markov Property and time homogeneity. Have you published the other method anywhere, or is this "standard knowledge"?

@PeterStrouvelle Thanks. I have not published it but I think it is too elementary to publish as a paper. Anyways, if you want, you can then mark as answer to remove the question from the unanswered tag. Or if you want to leave it open for further innovative answers then go ahead.


The book and you must be following a different convention in
restarting the process after a certain toss. For example, if I denote
$E(\tau|H_{1})$ to be the expected time After the first toss lands
heads to get the pattern and follow a similar convention, then we'll
end up with the following argument.

Applying law of total probability will lead you to the expression $E(\tau)=p(1+E(\tau|H_{1}))+q(1+E(\tau|T_{1}))=pE(\tau|H_{1})+qE(\tau|T_{1})+1$.

If you are following the convention that $E(\tau|H_{1})$ is the
expected time (not of the restarted process after the first toss but
rather the original process starting at time $0$ before the first
toss), then you'll end up with $pE(\tau|H_{1})+qE(\tau|T_{1})$ by the
usual law of total probability.

I'll follow the book's convention and explain:
Now again condition on the second step. Also note that $E(\tau|T_{1})=E(\tau)$ due to Markov Property. You'll get
\begin{align}E(\tau)&=p\bigg(p(1+E(\tau|H_{1}H_{2}))+q(1+E(\tau|H_{1}T_{2}))\bigg)+qE(\tau)+1\\\\
&=p(pE(\tau)+qE(\tau|H_{1}T_{2})+1)+qE(\tau)+1\\\\
&=p^{2}E(\tau)+p+pqE(\tau|H_{1}T_{2})+qE(\tau)+1\\\\
&=(p^{2}+q)E(\tau)+1+pq\bigg(p(1+E(\tau|H_{1}T_{2}H_{3}))+q(1+E(\tau|H_{1}T_{2}T_{3}))\bigg)\end{align}
Now $E(\tau|H_{1}T_{2}T_{3})=0$ and $E(\tau|H_{1}T_{2}H_{3})=E(\tau)$
So
\begin{align}E(\tau)&=(p^{2}+q)E(\tau)+1+pq(pE(\tau)+1)\\\\
&=(p^{2}+q+p^{2}q)E(\tau)+1\end{align}
Which gives you $E(\tau)=\frac{1}{1-p^{2}-q-p^{2}q}$. Well, now you need to factorize to see that $$1-p^{2}-q-p^{2}q=p-p^{2}-p^{2}q=p(1-p-pq)=p(q-pq)=pq(1-p)=pq^{2}$$
And hence $E(\tau)=\frac{1}{pq^{2}}$


We can solve it in general using a Gambling game analogy. The rigorous
justification of this requires Martingale Theory and the Optional
Sampling Theorem. I had written a proof of it but it is too long to be
posted in the answer. Here's the
link
for the complete proof

The Gambling game is as follows:
There is a casino with a rule that if a person with fortune $F$ enters the casino and bets on the coin landing heads and wins , then the casino pays him $F-\frac{F}{p}$ and if the person loses, he has to surrender his money and leave.
If the person bets on tails and wins then the casino gives him $F-\frac{F}{q}$ and if the person loses , then he again has to surrender his money and leave.
Now there are infinitely many gamblers who comes into the casino and bets in the following way:
The first person enters the casino with $1$ and bets it on heads. If he wins he now has $\frac{1}{p}$ and if he loses , he pays up and leaves. If he had won, then he bets all of his current fortune on the second toss being tails and then he pays up and leaves if he loses. If he wins, then he bets $\frac{1}{pq}$  on third toss being tails and pays up and leaves if he loses.
Similarly , the second gambler enters before the second toss and bets $1$ on heads and does exactly as the first gambler. This way the game continues and stops if at some time, any gambler has $ \frac{1}{pq^{2}}$ .
Now we can directly see that at $\tau_{100}$ , which is the first time we have the pattern $(HTT)$ , the money that entered the casino is $\tau_{100}$ and the $\tau_{100}-2$-th person has fortune $\frac{1}{pq^{2}}$. All others have $0$ money.
So as the game at each step was fair(expected profit of the person or the casino at each step is $0$), the expected net gain should also be $0$ . Thus $E(\tau_{100})=\frac{1}{pq^{2}}$ . (As $\tau_{100}$ was the money which has entered the casino)
Similarly, if you want to calculate $\tau_{010}$, then the $\tau_{010}$-th person would have fortune $\frac{1}{q}$ and the $\tau_{010}-2$-th person would have fortune $\frac{1}{pq^{2}}$. So, $E(\tau_{010})=\frac{1}{pq^{2}}+\frac{1}{q}$.
The interesting thing to observe is that even if $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$, then too $E(\tau_{010})>E(\tau_{100})$. The betting game analogy makes it clear as to why it should be so.
This is a very general method and can be used to calculate say $E(\tau_{111000110110})$ and patterns similar to those.

The method is actually quite nice!
